# Как сделать так, чтобы пользователь находясь на сайте мог ввести свое слово в форму и тем самым изменить title страницы, php

Tags: php

Нужен код на php который даст возможность пользователю изменить название title страницы, например ввести слово и чтоб оно появилось вместо дефолтного title

```
<script>
document.getElementById('raz').onclick = function() {
  var i = 'переменная';
  document.title = i;
}
</script>
```

Только эту переменную должен ввести сам пользователь через сайт

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать так, чтобы пользователь находясь на сайте мог ввести свое слово в форму и тем самым изменить title страницы, php code](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1269911/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8f%d1%81%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятно зачем Вам это нужно, но да ладно.
Основу я Вам написал, думаю для JS допишите.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title><? echo isset($_POST['title']) ? $_POST['title'] : 'Title'; ?></title>
    <head>

    <form action="/" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="title">
        <button type="submit">Сменить title</button>
    </form>
</html>
```

Comment: В итоге пишет NOT FOUND The requested URL was not found on this server. :(